# Alternative to a4j:mediaOutput with @Scope("conversation.access")

Tags: jakarta-ee, myfaces, ajax4jsf

I am using 
a4j:mediaOutput in my view and 
  a bean with @Scope("conversation.access")

i get NullpointerException for my paint-function called from mediaOutput. It seems this two(mediaOutput and conversation.access) dont work together.. at least i didnt found a solution. Does anyone have an idea how to get it work?

i already tried adding

s:conversationId value="#{conversation.id}"/> 
to mediaOutput, but it doesnt works for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: as far as i can remember, `a4j:mediaOutput` works only with a session scoped managed bean.